# Create several instances of a model in one page asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create several instances of my model:

```
    public int RestrictionID{get;set}
    public string portefeuille{get;set;}
    public int Min{get;set;}
    public int Max{get;set;}
```

So I created a ViewModel that is:

```
    public int ViewModelID{get;set;}
    public ICollection<Restriction> Restrictions{get;set;}
```

But when using entity framework, and trying to create an instance of ViewModel(that is several instance of Restriction) nothing appears (no input for the user), same as if the compiler don't know how to represent the input of Restrictions. So what I want is exactly the same input(properties) to be filled severeal times say 4 times. 
How can I achieve this? I need some help..

Thank you!

Comment: can you show where you build up your view model?  And where you display it to the user

Answer (score 0):

Does the ViewModelID serve any purpose? If not, you can just type your View to an IEnumerable of Restriction objects, like so:

```
@model IEnumerable<Restriction>
```

Then, in your view, you can enumerate the collection as you would any other:

```
@foreach (var restriction in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(_ => restriction.portefeuille)
    etc....
}
```

However worth noting that if you want to be able to edit and post back multiple instances of your model you will need to use an indexed loop like so:

```
@for (int i=0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(_ => Model[i].portefeuille)
    etc...
}
```

This allows the model binder to correctly bind the values.

If you do need the ViewModelId, then by all means use the ViewModel (it's good practice to use them anyway), and the same techniques still apply.

Comment: Yes exactly the ViewModelID doesn't serve for anything!

Comment: But the problem is that we cannot apply indexation [i] onto item of type IEnumerable<Restriction> I have an error on this.

Comment: Ah yes. Fair point. In that case you want to declare it as a List.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to understand, but I think your problem is merely that you have not initialized your `Restrictions`. For example:

```
model.Restrictions = new List<Restriction>
{
    new Restriction(),
    new Restriction(),
    new Restriction(),
    new Restriction()
}
```

Would give you four sets of `Restriction` fields, once you rendered this collection in your view. You might also what to do something like the following instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    model.Restrictions.Add(new Restriction);
}
```

That's a little less verbose, particularly if you were to have more than 4 items. Either way, the idea is that you need an actual `Restriction` instance in your collection for each set of fields you want rendered on the page.

If you need to add more dynamically, that's an entirely different issue that will require the use of JavaScript.